# When creating a table by Dbeaver client on Impala database, there is an error [Cloudera][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement

Tags: impala

When I creating a table on Impala databse server, using the `SQL`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_db.student
   (name STRING, age INT, contact INT );
```

### there is an error with the following message:

```
[Cloudera][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. 
Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, 
sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:AnalysisException: This Impala daemon is not 
ready to accept user requests.
Status: Waiting for catalog update from the StateStore.
), Query: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_db.student

(name STRING, age INT, contact INT )
```

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- I connected the impala server by `dbeaver` `using Impalajdbc41.jar`

The connection was estabilished successfully.

I have no idea why this happened, and how to solve it to create a table successfully?

Does anyone know the reason? And how to solve it?

Comment: can you run anything else like `show tables;` or `select current_timestamp()` ?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have uninstalled the impala server and install a new impala on Docker. But I meet antoher problem, like this:

Comment: impalad-main.cc:73] Invalid --buffer_pool_limit value, must be a percentage or positive bytes value or percentage: 85%
2023-04-14T02:06:25.319736243Z . Impalad exiting.

Comment: Do you have anyone idea to solve it?

Comment: no idea on this. pls post this as a questions someone will be able to answer

Comment: Thank you, Roy. I have sovled the problem by scaling the memory size to 16G.